# How do I get this tone

Tags: electric-guitar, tone, effects-pedal

How to get the Les Paul humbucker bridge pup tone like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yYqjcadwxo) nasal, airy, chime sound, I have a Les Paul standard 50s, a NUX MG30, and recently I'm obsessed with this tone, I tried for couple of hours to get this tone but didn't catch exactly.

---

This is what I've got for now:

```
AMP: Super reverb  Gain: 5.3, Master 9.7, Bass 3.1 Middle 3, Treb 4.9, bright Off, Bias 4.5, Level 9
Pedal: half-engaged
Compress: K Comp with Sustain 4.3, Level 7, Clipping 7.1
EFX: Morning DRV, Volume 6, Drive 6, Tone: 4
Reverb: HALL with Delay 2.9, Pred: 6.4, Liveness: 8.8 Level: 4
IR: Off

Guitar: Bridge pickup Volume: 8, Tone: 10.
```

Answer with your findings or comment on what you think, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like the "Super RVB" model might be a good starting point. Listening to some demos my personal take is that the NUX MG30 seems to lose a little flavor somewhere inside, so you might have a hard time getting all the same nuance that Robben Ford is getting.

Comment: Hi Todd, "Super RVB" is good I'll try later next time, I'v tried VT Clean the most, tweaking some effects like the eat-dst effect, ac boost, maybe 3 or 4 amps and on/off of PAs. Plus that dialed in many of the preset models. I think many of the results sound either too harsh, or too bassy.

Comment: VT Clean? That model doesn't seem to be listed on the NUX web site? I would go with Super RVB and play with that a lot and see what you can get.

Comment: You might check if your box' firmware version can be updated, if I remember it correctly this efx model is a bundled one.

Comment: Bear in mind also that the way the string is plucked, and where it's plucked will make a marked difference to the sound, no matter what effect is used.

Comment: [How to get Robben Ford's guitar tone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBHuo7xjySo&t=915s) Work on the clean tone first. Then flip the switch and it basically sounds like that even w/o the five pedals in front of this guy. *'he does have a light touch, but he can dig in as well'* - dude's got a reverb pedal but in the beginning he says Ford gets it from the spring in the amp.

Comment: "The trick to getting a Page-esquie guitar tone is to use the volume on your amp rather than the gain knob. [...] EQ up full on your amp (literally bass 10, mids 10 and treble 10) and let your guitar and fingers do the work!" https://blog.andertons.co.uk/sound-like/sound-like-jimmy-page-led-zeppelin

Comment: The youtube link at ~15:20 "This is the clean sound from the amp".... is that not the sound that you're talking about? Or five seconds later he flips the pick up switch... That one? That's the amp and the guitar. No pedals *necessary*. - On your Fender; prob needs set at 11. On a Marshal half stack, 2.5 will do.